# How to get the Parallax scrolling to consume the full width and height of a screen?

Tags: html, css

How can I get the image to cover the whole screen?

CSS:

```
.parallaxBg {
    background-image: url("image_test.jpg");

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parallaxBg">
</div>
```

Comment: i made mine by having a parallax intro and paralax botom div then nested the content in betwwen... that covered the whole page... the css was quite simmilar to yours

Comment: _"How can I get the image to cover the whole screen?"_ - by getting the element that contains this background image to cover the whole screen ... and that is probably not such a unique and new question, that it could not be researched ...

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the body height to 100%:

```
body, html {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

And the parallaxBg height to 100% too:

```
height: 100%;
```

Example:

```css
body, html {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
  }
  #parallaxBg {
   /* The image used */
      background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/800/any");

      /* Full height */
      height: 100%; 

      /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
  }

  .text {
   position: relative;
   top: 600px;
   height: 300px;
   font-size: 2em;
   background: blue;
   padding: 2em;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parallaxBg">
 <div class="text">
  Bacon ipsum dolor amet corned beef doner pig filet mignon t-bone pancetta beef tongue ground round meatball pork belly landjaeger tail. Turducken flank pork t-bone, shoulder pastrami short loin drumstick jowl tail bresaola strip steak tenderloin frankfurter. Corned beef short loin chuck venison pork jerky. Jowl leberkas cupim turkey flank drumstick porchetta strip steak ham hock tail shoulder ball tip brisket tri-tip. Beef ribs bresaola short ribs cow tenderloin, jerky ball tip shankle pastrami shoulder t-bone.
 </div>
```

Hope it's what you're asking for!